# Dropdown List entries based on previous Dropdown list selection

Tags: excel-formula

I have an Excel Workbook with a cell with a list data validation with countries: USA, UK, RUSSIA, FRANCE.

I have another cell with cities such that when I click a country, say, USA in the first cell, the second cell populates it's drop-down with the cities in this country, like NY, DC.

I lastly have a third cell which also has a drop-down and whose values depend on what is selected in the second cell and it consists of languages like Spanish, English, Arabic. I have tried several custom lists, but I am only able to get the first cell right.

Comment: Have a look at the example solution I did, you should be able to craft your solution from there : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51090963/4961700

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. Ranges are highlighted with same color, with header as the name of the range.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: changed last photo to show the formula you would plug into source: in data validation window for cell under languages. data validation window size cant be changed ! (at least not easily)

Comment: This sure is an answer. Thank you.

Comment: I am getting some error when marking as an answe, but will do it again....

Comment: please do ! and glad that I could help