# Excel Drop-Down Menu with dynamic Content

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, excel-tables

I want to build a Drop-Down menu in my excle-table which automatic updates itsself if the original table gets additional content.

e.g.:

```
France  
Germany  
Italy
```

is my reference table, name "countries".

Normally i do my drop-down menus by selecting the cells, defining a name with the name manager and building the drop down menu with the data validation, selecting list and type in "`=countries`".

But when my programm now adds e.g. Spain under the table, its not in the drop down menu.  Is it possible to reference the drop down menu to the head of a column of a table, so the content of the column gets displayed?

Comment: have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51090963/4961700

Comment: Sounds like you are using an approach that has worked for me in the past.  Are you setting up your list of countries as a table?  If not, then make a table for your list and then select your data field, not the header, and define a name pointing to that.  As you add items to your list you should automatically get the updated choices in your drop-down menus.