# Using Two Drop Down Menus to collect specific information from another sheet

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, spreadsheet, vlookup

Good afternoon!

I'm trying to make an easy lookup page for an excel workbook that has 7-9 different sheets. Essentially, I have course listings for each college of a university and some information from each one that I need to pull, and I had the formula working, but once I added in more data and formatting, I'm getting a Value Not Available Error.

So, I have a drop down menu to select a college - "College of Arts and Media", for example.
Then I have a space for someone to type a specific course code - "ART 112"

Once they fill out those two things, I have a few boxes of "Results" that I want to populate.

My first box has this formula:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(B7,INDIRECT("'"&B3&"'!$A$2:$H$100"),2,0)=0, "No", "Yes")
```

With B7 being the box where the course code was typed in, and B3 being the college selection that matches to the sheet where the data lives. (The course code is in Column B of the college sheets.)

My second through fifth boxes have this formula (with different columns selected in the VLOOKUP pull):

```
=VLOOKUP(B7,INDIRECT("'"&B3&"'!$A$1:$H$100"),6,0)
```

These are just pulling information from other columns in the same row as the course specified.

I've been puzzling over this for an hour, and I can't figure out what I did to make it stop working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Difficult to debug something like this (as you already have experienced). I think that the college values in B3 are not a problem, since that would likely give a reference error, so I suspect it is something about the course lookup value in B3. Allowing someone to type the specific course code allows room for slight typing errors that would result in an N/A. Is it possible that there is an extra space in Column A on the College Sheet? Not much room, but I might try creating a dropdownlist for courses by naming each course list for the college and using =indirect(B3) as the source of the list.

Comment: I show one possible option you could look at here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51090963/4961700 - if it proves helpful give it a vote...