# EPPlus - Problems With Advanced List Validation

Tags: asp.net, excel, epplus

I have a little problem when I charge two *ListValidation*, the first one call the cells with name *CATEGORIES* and the second one is dependent on its select category. I write a list of categories and sub-categories on *Categories* sheet and get the data in the *Principal* sheet.
The problem is when I select an option in the "Categories" list, the second list with its sub-categories doesn't work. I have to enter in data validation and apply the configurations and then the second list works.
Please help

**EDIT**

[Code](https://image.ibb.co/eKymW8/1.png)

[First List Works](https://image.ibb.co/mVHPJo/2.png)

[Second List Doesn't work](https://image.ibb.co/c8Zh4T/3.png)

[Menu Data Validation And Accept](https://image.ibb.co/j65ddo/4.png)

[Second List Works](https://image.ibb.co/g2fpjT/5.png)

[Categories And Sub-Categories](https://image.ibb.co/fPrJdo/6.png)

Comment: Without data it is difficult to work out what is happening, but have a look at this and if it helps upvote it : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51090963/4961700

Comment: Correction in grammar and formatted.