# Excel: dependent drop-down lists

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Apologies if this is a stupid question, but I cannot seem to be able to find a solution.

I have this table:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cS2E.png)

In two separate sheets (Store 1 and Store 2), I have the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhPNs.png)

In both sheets (Store 1 and Store 2) I'd like to have a drop-down list so that if, for example, "Alcohol" is selected in col. B, under "Category" in column C the drop-down menu will show me only two options ("Wine" and "Spirit"). If then "Spirit" is selected, in column D the drop-down would show me only "Red Wine" and "White Wine".

The "Group" is not really a problem as I can add a helper column to my first table and then use the UNIQUE function. I'm not sure how to proceed with "Category" and "Subcategory".

Hope I could explain myself!

Comment: Do something like this and vote for it if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51090963/4961700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dynamic arrays...

[image: Screenshot of solution]

1. `A1:C8` contains what the OP calls `Store1`.
2. `E1:H5` contains `Store2`.
3. Rows `10`, `13-16` and `19-22` contain from column `F` onwards the
   dynamic arrays which provide the drop-down lists for the cells in
   `Store2`.

**Defining the dynamic arrays:**

Use the following formulas:

Cell `F10`: `=TOROW(UNIQUE(A2:A8))`

Cell `F13`: `=TOROW(UNIQUE((FILTER(B$2:B$8,A$2:A$8=F2))))`
Copy to range `F14:F16`

Cell `F19`: `=TOROW(FILTER(C$2:C$8,(A$2:A$8=F2)*(B$2:B$8=G2)))`
Copy to range `F20:F22`

Unusually, these array formulas contain absolute elements ($ signs) in the cell references. These are required because of the copy/paste operations noted above.

**Assigning the drop-down lists for cells in range F2:H5**

Cell `F2`
The *Source:* field of the Data Validation dialogue is assigned with the value `=$F$10#`
Copy cell `F2` to range `F3:F5`

Cell `G2`
The *Source:* field of the Data Validation dialogue is assigned with the value `=F13#`
Copy cell `G2` to range `G3:G5`

Cell `H2`
The *Source:* field of the Data Validation dialogue is assigned with the value `=F19#`
Copy cell `H2` to range `H3:H5`

**Notes**

1. It is necessary to place the dynamic arrays forming the dropdown lists into the workbook because the *Source:* field of the Data Validation dialogue does not (yet!?) allow dynamic array functions such `UNIQUE`, `FILTER` and `TOROW`.
2. `#CALC` values are shown when it is not possible to evaluate a dynamic array. Eg the formula for cell `F15` contains the formula snippet `FILTER(B$2:B$8,A$2:A$8=F4)`. However, no value has yet been chosen in cell `F4`, meaning the snippet cannot be evaluated and so returns `#CALC`. As soon as a value is entered into cell `F4` (using its dropdown), the dynamic array appears in `F15` and the cells to its right.
3. Unlike the answer referenced by @Solar Mike in his comment (and which pre-dates Excel's dynamic arrays), there is no requirement that the data in `Store1` be ordered by `Group` then `Category`.