# How to create grouped dropdowns from one list EXCEL

Tags: excel, list, dropdown

I have one list with the following info:

| CATEGORY | ITEM |
| --- | --- |
| Fruit | Orange |
| Vegetable | Lettuce |
| Fruit | Apple |
| Fruit | Pear |
| Vegetable | Carrot |
| Meat | Chicken |

I'm looking to create a drop-down list based on category. So, if I select fruit, then I want all the fruit from the main list to be an option on the drop down.

**CATEGORY SELECTION** = Fruit
**Drop down options**
Orange
Apple
Pear

I'd prefer to not have to create each category list in its own column as I just want the drop-down selections to pull from my one list. Is that possible in Excel?

Comment: So do you have the data structured in that way? And may I know what is the Excel Version you are using? If I ask you since you have data structured in that way, you will need helper columns, will that be okay with you?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76761601/excel-dependent-drop-down-lists/76764165#76764165

Answer (score 0):

Copy this code to the sheet's code pane.

Assign a reference (command) button on the ribbon, or create a ControlButton on the sheet for the veget() sub.

Select the sheet where the data are. Click the created item. Click the generated ComboBox dropdown arrow. For the first, the Category members will appear. Select an item and click again the dropdown arrow. The members of the selected category appear.

To select a new category click the reference (command) button again.

```vb
Dim cl As Integer, filt As String, combo As OLEObject
Private Sub gt6r4371ß_Change()
Set combo = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("gt6r437lß")
If cl = 2 Then Exit Sub
If cl = 0 Then
  ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
  cl = 1
  filt = combo.Object.text
  combo.Object.Clear
Else
  Set datarng = Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)
  For Each cell In datarng
    If cell = filt Then
      combo.Object.AddItem cell.Offset(0, 1).value
    End If
  Next cell
  cl = 2
End If
End Sub

Private Sub veget()
cl = 2
On Error Resume Next
Set combo = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("gt6r437lß")
On Error GoTo 0
If combo Is Nothing Then
  ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add "forms.combobox.1", , , , , , , 250, 100, 100, 20
  Set combo = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Count)
  combo.Name = "gt6r437lß"
End If
Set datarng = Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)
combo.Object.Clear
datarng.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, , , True
For Each cell In Range("A2:A" & 
  Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
  combo.Object.AddItem cell.value
Next cell
cl = 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In a cell, let's say `A1`, use `Data Validation` and enter each **Category** (e.g.,`Fruit`) in a list separated by commas. ([Data validation list video](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-drop-down-list-7693307a-59ef-400a-b769-c5402dce407b))

Sort your table by **Category**. Now use named ranges ([Named Range video](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64)) to easily reference the item ranges in your **Item** column. Create a named range for each set of items in the **Item** column. Name the ranges according to the category the items belong to (i.e., `Fruit`, `Vegetable`, `Meat`).

In a 2nd cell, say `B1`, use `Data Validation` again. Under the `Allow` option, select `List`. In the `Source` box, type `INDIRECT(A1)` and click `OK`.

Note that you can create a named range with non-contiguous cells (by holding down `CTRL` and left clicking to select), so sorting by **Item** might not be necessary. I do not advise doing so.