# Excel related category dropdowns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data rows grouped like this:

[image]

What I need to do is to make new sheet with only three dropdowns lists, which would sort these categories. For example after selecting CATEGORY, second dropdown should show its unique subcategories, after selecting subcategory, third select should show it's sub-sub-categories. How I could achieve that?
To explain screenshot, it should be like this:
First select should contain only 'automobiliu-technika'
After selecting it, second dropdown should contain options: 'ispardavimas', 'automagnetolos', 'garsiakalbiai', after selecting for example 'automagnetolos,' third select should contain only 'priedai-4'

Comment: Perhaps something like : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51090963/4961700