I can't get dependent combo boxes filtered to according to what has been selected in other combo boxes

All values in the combo boxes are derived from a worksheet within the same workfile. Each combo box corresponds to a specific column in that worksheet.
Ideally, the combo boxes should interact with each other to filter their options. However, currently, they are not filtering properly. Instead, they're displaying all unique values from their respective columns.
The combo box named cboFilterFoodProduct is supposed to provide a final selection from column B in the worksheet, based on the filtered values from the other combo boxes. However, it's not functioning correctly; it doesn't allow me to select anything from it.

I expect that each combo box filters its options based on the selections made in the other combo boxes. Ultimately, I anticipate that the combo box named cboFilterFoodProduct will present a final value from its list, taking into account the filtered choices from the other combo boxes.
Here the current code:
Public comboBoxCaller As String

Private Sub PopulateComboBoxFromRange(ByVal comboBox As comboBox, ByVal data As Range)
    Dim uniqueItems As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set uniqueItems = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In data
        If Not cell.Value = "" And Not uniqueItems.Exists(cell.Value) Then
            uniqueItems.Add cell.Value, Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    comboBox.Clear
    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In uniqueItems.keys
        comboBox.AddItem key
    Next key
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateComboBoxFromColumn(ByVal comboBox As comboBox, ByVal column As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Nutritional_Value_Database")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, column).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim uniqueItems As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In ws.Range(column & "2:" & column & lastRow)
        If Not cell.Value = "" And Not uniqueItems.Exists(cell.Value) Then
            Call uniqueItems.Add(cell.Value, Nothing)
        End If
    Next cell

    comboBox.Clear
    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In uniqueItems.keys
        comboBox.AddItem key
    Next key
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateComboBoxFromKeys(ByVal comboBox As comboBox, ByVal keys As Variant)
    comboBox.Clear
    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In keys
        comboBox.AddItem key
    Next key
End Sub

Private Sub cboProductType_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    comboBoxCaller = ""
    PopulateComboBoxFromColumn cboProductType, "A"
    PopulateComboBoxFromColumn cboCountryOrigin, "J"
    PopulateComboBoxFromColumn cboStoreAvailability, "K"
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateFilter()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Nutritional_Value_Database")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim productType As String
    Dim countryOrigin As String
    Dim storeAvailability As String

    productType = Trim(cboProductType.Value)
    countryOrigin = Trim(cboCountryOrigin.Value)
    storeAvailability = Trim(cboStoreAvailability.Value)

    Dim filteredProduct As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim filteredCountry As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim filteredStore As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim foodProducts As New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        Dim prodVal As String
        Dim countryVal As String
        Dim storeVal As String
        Dim foodProdVal As String

        prodVal = ws.Cells(i, "A").Value
        countryVal = ws.Cells(i, "J").Value
        storeVal = ws.Cells(i, "K").Value
        foodProdVal = ws.Cells(i, "B").Value

        If prodVal Like "*" & productType & "*" Or productType = "" Then
            If Not filteredProduct.Exists(prodVal) Then filteredProduct.Add prodVal, Nothing
        End If
        
        If countryVal Like "*" & countryOrigin & "*" Or countryOrigin = "" Then
            If Not filteredCountry.Exists(countryVal) Then filteredCountry.Add countryVal, Nothing
        End If
        
        If storeVal Like "*" & storeAvailability & "*" Or storeAvailability = "" Then
            If Not filteredStore.Exists(storeVal) Then filteredStore.Add storeVal, Nothing
        End If

        If (prodVal Like "*" & productType & "*" Or productType = "") And
           (countryVal Like "*" & countryOrigin & "*" Or countryOrigin = "") And
           (storeVal Like "*" & storeAvailability & "*" Or storeAvailability = "") Then
            If Not foodProducts.Exists(foodProdVal) Then foodProducts.Add foodProdVal, Nothing
        End If
    Next i

    If comboBoxCaller <> "cboProductType" Then UpdateComboBox cboProductType, filteredProduct.keys
    If comboBoxCaller <> "cboCountryOrigin" Then UpdateComboBox cboCountryOrigin, filteredCountry.keys
    If comboBoxCaller <> "cboStoreAvailability" Then UpdateComboBox cboStoreAvailability, filteredStore.keys
    UpdateComboBox cboFilterFoodproduct, foodProducts.keys
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateComboBox(ByVal comboBox As MSForms.comboBox, ByVal keys As Variant)
    Dim current As String
    current = comboBox.Value

    comboBox.Clear
    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In keys
        comboBox.AddItem key
    Next key

    If Not IsError(Application.Match(current, comboBox.List, 0)) Then
        comboBox.Value = current
    ElseIf comboBox.ListCount > 0 Then
        comboBox.ListIndex = 0  ' Optionally set to the first item if no current value is valid
    End If
End Sub




Well, perhaps a different approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51090963/4961700

Please add a screenshot of your source data for the dropdowns...

What's the change event code for comboBox?

Here the screenshot for the source data @TimWilliams: file:///C:/Users/FelixSchubert/Downloads/Screenshot%202024-05-03%20094938.png

I don’t have access to your C drive
